# Hide all buttons connected to same IB Outlet

Tags: ios, objective-c, interface-builder

I have 6 checkmark images that are all connected to the same IB Outlet. I have set a unique tag value for each image in IB. I want to hide all of them in `viewDidLoad`

I tried `_checkmark.hidden=NO;` but that only hides the last button connected to the outlet.

Is there a clean way to hide all of the image at once, rather than

```
[_checkmark viewWithTag:0].hidden = YES; 
[_checkmark viewWithTag:1].hidden = YES;
[_checkmark viewWithTag:2].hidden = YES; 
//... and so on
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Make sure your collection property is `IBOutletCollection`, connect all of `UIImageView` with this property.
- Hide images with the code below.

  ```
  for (UIImageView *image in _checkmarkArray) {
    image.hidden = YES;
  }
  ```

Comment: @matt i just give him a right answer. Make sure you tried and tested your code before answer. If you give a right answer, of course i won't write anything